# Навигация только по элементам на странице клавишей tab (при этом не попадать в адресную строку!)

Tags: javascript, html

Я обдумываю навигацию по элементам на странице. И рассматриваю два варианта (реализацию обоих пока не знаю) - стрелками или клавишей tab. Решил начать с tab. В общем, на странице всего пока два элемента `<input tabindex="2">` (вверху) и `<textarea autofocus tabindex="1">` (ниже). При загрузке страницы курсор стоит на `<textarea>`, нажимаю tab, попадаю в `<input>`, еще раз tab - уже в адресной строке. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии Tab переключаться только между `<input>` и `<textarea>` и не попадать в адресную строку? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе нужен javascript, в котором onkeydown() на элементах input и textarea с keyCode == 9 будет вызывать focus() следующего элемента. Вот набросал пример.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function uniKeyCode(event, element) {
      var key = event.keyCode;
      if (key == 9) {
        console.log("Unicode KEY code: " + key + " TAB Element: " + element);
        document.getElementById(element).focus();
        return false;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="input" onkeydown="return(uniKeyCode(event,'textarea')); "><br />
  <textarea id="textarea" onkeydown="return(uniKeyCode(event,'input')); "></textarea><br />
</body>

</html>
```